# How can I set desktop icons to auto-align to the right side of the screen?

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons

Now that unity has the bar on the left side of the screen, I find that it ends up obscuring desktop icons since desktop icons auto align top-bottom/left-right. To correct this I need to constantly keep dragging icons to the right so that they're not underneath the bar, but this isn't an elegant solution as new icons will be placed as far top-left as possible.

Is there a way I can set the desktop icons in Ubuntu to auto-align on the right side of the screen? For example, top-bottom/right-left?

Answer (score 3):

this has been a nautilus bug since they first came out with nautilus:

http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42479

if you download the source you can look at it yourself: currently tbrl (top-bottom-right-left, the ordering you want) isn't implemented and just uses tblr instead. so you have to hack it yourself or wait for an official fix. there seems to be not much progress in it though.